# How do I control one EV3 using another through bluetooth and LabVIEW?

Tags: ev3, bluetooth, labview

I have LabVIEW 2014 and I'd like to control make one EV3 move forward using another through bluetooth using LabVIEW, and I don't want to have to use the computer as a relay. How do I do this?

Comment: This is not EV3 and does not use LabVIEW, but maybe you can use it as a reference to develop real time Bluetooth communication between two systems: http://www.philohome.com/nxtjoystick/joystick.htm